# How to train f(x)=x*x using Artificial neural network?

Tags: regression

let's take some training data of size 100

```
x_input = [1,2,3,4,.....,100]
y_label = [1,4,9,16,....,10000]
```

Now, let's consider that we don't know the function `f` where `f(x_input) = x_input`<sup>2</sup>

How should we train it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question lies [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25609347/can-neural-networks-approximate-any-function-given-enough-hidden-neurons).

Personally, since I can see the high autocorrelation of your input signal x (obvious that x(t+1) = x(t) + 1), you could treat it as timeseries and use an [LSTM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_short-term_memory)-RNN to model the nonlinear function y. For simplicity, you could always treat your data as [iid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_and_identically_distributed_random_variables) and, under this assumption, use an [MLP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilayer_perceptron).

Comment: after visiting the stackoverflow link, I visited this [ https://towardsdatascience.com/can-neural-networks-really-learn-any-function-65e106617fc6 ], which was very helpful.